# Why does conforming to Strideable change how multiplication is evaluated?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I created an infinite loop by conforming a Swift struct to the Strideable protocol. I reduced the problem to the following case.

```
struct T: Strideable {
    func advanced(by n: Int) -> T { return T() }
    func distance(to other: T) -> Int {
        print("Hello")
        return self == T() ? 0 : 1
    }
}

print(T() == T())
```

Running this code in a playground results in an unending stream of "Hello"s. If `struct T: Strideable` is replaced with `struct T: Equatable`, "true" prints as I would expect.

I suspect that there is a default implementation of Equatable for types conforming to Strideable which is distinct from the auto-synthesized implementation for structs whose members are all equatable. The struct in my project has many members, so I would not like to manually implement a member-wise comparison.

Why does conforming to Strideable change how equality is implemented, and is there a way to recover the expected behavior without manually implementing Equatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's from apple documents:

**Important**
 The Strideable protocol provides default implementations for the equal-to (==)  and less-than (<) operators that depend on the Stride type’s implementations. If a type conforming to Strideable is its own Stride type, it must provide concrete implementations of the two operators to avoid infinite recursion.

So either you provide the "==" and "<" implementation like this :

```
 struct Temp: Strideable {
var error = 1
func advanced(by n: Int) -> Temp { return Temp() }
func distance(to other: Temp)  -> Int {
    print("hello")
    return self == other ? 0 : 1
}
static func == (left : T, right: T){
    print("great")
}
}
```

or use some value to manager the stride property. like `var location : Int = 0`

Comment: Since the Stride type of Temp is Int, why does Apple's warning apply here? It does not appear to me that Temp is its own Stride type.

Comment: Oh, I understand. The == from Strideable tries to see if the distance between two values is 0. The problem here is that it cannot even compute the distance without knowing equality.

I still wonder if there is a way to avoid writing out the memberwise equality though.

Comment: You don’t need to override == here. You can add an int property to differentiate each structure. Add a location property here and make sure each one has a unique value.

Comment: You may find an example here. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/strideable.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my actual distance function, I need to compare self to a special value memberwise because distances are computed differently for that value. If I want to use == for memberwise equality inside the distance function, I must manually implement equality as memberwise (unless I am mistaken).